# Hibernate search : Sorting with filter on nested object, how to?

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I have to code an hibernate search query (**for elastic search database backend**) which include a conditionnal sort of this kind :

```
Date dateOfBirth = new Date('01/01/2000');
Integer age = 10;
if (dateOfBirth == null) {
   //then sort by age
}
else {
   //sort by date of birth
}
```

I found an example to code this conditionnal sort inside Hibernate Search Reference, it can be done like this (quoted example) :

```
List<Author> hits = searchSession.search( Author.class )
.where( f -> f.matchAll() )
.sort( f -> f.field( "books.pageCount" )
.mode( SortMode.AVG )
.filter( pf -> pf.match().field( "books.genre" )
.matching( Genre.CRIME_FICTION ) ) )
.fetchHits( 20 );
```

My problem is that I hibernate search throws an exception at runtime. My sort filter code :

```
 case DATE_SIGNATURE:
                FieldSortOptionsStep bivSortFirst = f.field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE)
                        .filter(fa ->
                                {
                                    PredicateFinalStep a = fa.bool(bo -> bo.must(fa.exists().field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE)));
                                    return fa.bool(b0 -> b0.must(a));
                                }
                        );
                FieldSortOptionsStep bivSortSecond = f.field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.ACTE + "." + Acte_.SIGNATURE)
                        .filter(fa ->
                                {
                                    PredicateFinalStep a = fa.bool(bo -> bo.mustNot(fa.exists().field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE)));
                                    PredicateFinalStep b = fa.bool(bo -> bo.must(fa.exists().field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.ACTE + "." + Acte_.SIGNATURE)));
                                    return fa.bool(b0 -> b0.must(a).must(b));
                                }
                        );
                sortFieldOrderedList.add(bivSortFirst);
                sortFieldOrderedList.add(bivSortSecond);
                break;
```

In the above example, I sort on two fields by priority. The first is assimilable to 'date of birth' and the second to 'age'. At runtime, the filter are not accepted by hibernate search and then throws an exception like follows :

The error message :

> HSEARCH400604: Invalid sort filter: field 'vente.acte.signature' is
> not contained in a nested object. Sort filters are only available if
> the field to sort on is contained in a nested object. Context: field
> 'vente.acte.signature'

I read to do so, I need to go for 'inner_hits' query for elastic search. But how do I do this with hibernate search API ?

Thanks.

EDIT : Hibernate mapping of classes :

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Depot {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vente_fk")
    protected Vente vente;
                
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {
    Vente_.ID,
    Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE,
    Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE_ACTE,
    Vente_.ACTE + "." + Acte_.SIGNATURE,
        and much more
    }
    public Vente getVente() {
            return this.vente;
        }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Vente {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = Depot_.VENTE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Depot> depot = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "acte_fk")
    protected Acte acte;
...
    @AssociationInverseSide(inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = Acte_.VENTE)))
    @IndexedEmbedded
    public Acte getActe() {
        return this.acte;
    }
...
}

@Entity
public class Acte {
...
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.YES)
    protected Date signature;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = Vente_.ACTE)
    protected Set<Vente> vente = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Date getSignature() {
        return this.signature;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: You need to show your model in order for people to understand what you're trying to do. In particular: `Vente`, `Acte`, and any superclass or superinterface.

Comment: Also, `Depot`, of course.

Comment: Depot is the root document (@ Indexed).
Vente is @ indexEmbedded.
Acte is @ IndexEmbedded.

The indexed document looks like json (_source is Depot):

_source {
vente: {
acte: {
signature: {
}
}
}
Is it sufficient ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. I need to see the actual annotated properties, such as `Depot#vente`, `Vente#acte`, etc.

Comment: ok added into the edit part.

Comment: Whatever I put, I have the same error :
FieldSortOptionsStep bivSortFirst = f.field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE)
                        .filter(fa -> fa.exists().field(Depot_.VENTE + "." + Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE));

Even if I filter on a NON-nested field, for example, DEPOT_.A_DATE, I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, for each `Depot`, there is at most one `Acte` and one `Vente`. So what you're trying to do is a bit exotic, as filtering in sorts is generally used on multi-valued nested objects.

The reason it's not working is you didn't mark the `@IndexedEmbedded` objects (vente, acte) as "nested"; as explained in the documentation, filtering only works on [nested objects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-sort-common-filter). And "nested" has [a very precise meaning](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-structure-nested), it's not synonmymous with "indexed-embedded".

However, I think the whole approach is wrong in this case: you shouldn't use filtering. I'm quite sure that even if you mark the `@IndexedEmbedded` objects as "nested", you will face other problems, because what you're trying to do isn't the intended purpose of filtering. One of those problems could be performance; nested documents mean runtime joins, and runtime joins aren't cheap.

Instead, consider solving this problem at indexing time. Instead of trying to figure out which date to use for each document when searching, do that when indexing:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Depot {
    //...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vente_fk")
    protected Vente vente;
                
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {
    Vente_.ID,
    Vente_.DATE_FOR_SORT, // <================= ADD THIS
    Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE,
    Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE_ACTE,
    Vente_.ACTE + "." + Acte_.SIGNATURE,
        //and much more
    })
    public Vente getVente() {
            return this.vente;
        }

}

@Entity
public class Vente {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = Depot_.VENTE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Depot> depot = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "acte_fk")
    protected Acte acte;
//...
    @AssociationInverseSide(inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = Acte_.VENTE)))
    @IndexedEmbedded
    public Acte getActe() {
        return this.acte;
    }

    // v================= ADD THIS
    @Transient
    @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = {
        @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = Vente_.DATE_SIGNATURE)),
        @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = Vente_.ACTE), @PropertyValue(propertyName = Acte_.SIGNATURE)),
    })
    public Date getDateForSort() {
        if ( getDateSignature() != null ) {
            return getDateSignature();
        }
        else {
            return getActe().getSignature();
        }
    }
    // ^================= ADD THIS
//...
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I did already what you said : delete this filter that doesn't work and pre-compute this dynamic sort value (but at the cost of maintaining this index value up to date). Thank you for your advice about nested object, i didn't know that notion. But the manner elastic search store its documents tell me that I indexed my content like nested and not flattened : A document is a json tree, not only properties under _source {}. My fields are mentionned like nested with only @IndexEmbedded : Field1 + "." + Field2 + "." + .... etc.

Comment: Even in Elasticsearch, by default the index content is flattened. It doesn't matter if your JSON appears as nested: the index is not structured the same way, and by default it is flattened. See the [`nested` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), which is opt-in, and the [`object` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), which is the default.